# ESXi Simple Network

Tags: windows-server-2008, windows-server-2008-r2, routing, vmware-esxi, windows-server-2012

I'm in the process of revamping my network with the use of ESXi. The structure of my network before was as follows:

```
Public -> Win 2008 R2 Server NIC#1
          ADDS/DNS/DHCP/RRAS NIC#2 -> Physical Switch (LAN)
```

This setup provided all my network clients with routing and internet... I decided to take my network a bit more seriously and upgrade, and installed ESXi instead of Win 2008 R2 and I wanted to have several Win 2012 clients to compartmentalize the jobs the server was doing before.

I have 2 NICs at my disposal (can buy another one if necessary), but I can't wrap my mind around the networking aspect now.

Win 2008 R2 was doing all the routing before, but if I connect the ESXi host to the new Windows 2012 VM (which handles LAN routing) and that VM goes down, I lose access to the ESXi host. At the same time, I don't want to use a hardware router because I liked the topology of my network before, with all the traffic passing through a Windows Server which functioned as a firewall as well.

How should I approach this problem?

Comment: Get a hardware firewall appliance. An OS, regardless of whether it's a server or not, is NOT a proper router.

Comment: What's wrong with using Windows for routing, it worked perfectly for my network for over a year.

Comment: As you've experienced, if it goes down for any reason you lose all network access. Hardware is much more reliable ...or OSs designed for these purposes.

Comment: I understand, but this is what I have to work with - I would much rather use Windows 2012 for routing and firewall which I can monitor and control directly rather than my DD-WRT router.

Comment: You're asking a "should" question, and the most common answer these days is that you "should" user a dedicated hardware firewall and router. And one that cost a bit more than a DD-WRT. How much is reliability worth, to your business?

Comment: Are you saying that you moved from hyper-v to esxi why not move to w2k12 hyperv?

Comment: @NathanC - even a "firewall appliance" runs an OS. Also, I've seen some very large deployments, pushing huge amounts of traffic, using pfSense (FreeBSD) for routing and firewall, with outstanding reliability and a fraction of the cost of what it would have taken to purchase an "appliance".

Comment: Now...that said, my personal (biased) feeling is that Windows makes a rubbish router. If you want a "software" router, go with pfSense.

Comment: @mfinni I'm asking a should question in the confines of the variables that I have to work with: no hardware router, as many NICs, external traffic must pass through a VM before reaching LAN.

Comment: @EEAA I want to use win2012 as a DC and the DHCP is tied to it, and I never had trouble with win2008 providing routing, it did it perfectly

Comment: @tonyroth I have no experience with hyperv and my friends turned me on to ESXi because they use it at work

Comment: You said you're doing this for clients. I wouldn't buy services from someone that's offering them using what you're using.

Comment: Windows does great as a DHCP server (which is not tied to being a domain controller, as you state.) That has nothing, absolutely nothing, to do with it also being a border router.

Comment: @mfinni hopefully clients mean just internal clients not external paying clients!  Still an issue either way...

Comment: @mfinni I bet my android clients will be the first ones to cough up the dough.

Comment: @tonyroth I'm gonna use hyperv.

Comment: if you are really moving to hyperv get the free hyper-v server 2012 version!

Comment: I did and I got everything configured perfectly, thanks

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Your design is flawed and as others have said in comments, you will most likely need a separate piece of hardware to do the job, whether it's a dedicated firewall/router (i.e. SonicWall, Cisco, Juniper) or software appliance (i.e. pfSense, IPCop, IPFire).

Your network would then look like this:

```
Public <--> Router <--> Physical Switch <--> ESXi Host <--> Windows 2008 Server
                              |                 |
                              |                 +<--------> Other VMs
                              |
                              +<------------> Other LAN devices
```

This is typically the way things are set up in most enterprise environments - you have dedicated (and ideally, HA/redundant) hardware handling your NAT routing.

The reason for the separate hardware is that as you've experienced, if your router lives on the same hardware as your ESXi host and you lose the VM (or even the host), you also lose routing (along with any other service hosted by the VM/host - DNS/DHCP, etc.)

There's also an attack vector and a resource efficiency angle - are you confident enough having Windows on your edge (publicly accessible) network? Typically (I know this is subjective), a full-fledged O/S has a higher attack vector than a dedicated appliance.

Dedicated appliances have been designed from the ground up to do the job, and so have an incredibly stripped-down OS (as has been pointed out, even dedicated appliances have an OS of some description).

Low-down: get yourself a dedicated firewall; you will save yourself a lot of head/heartache in the long-run.